# Pyspark using customized function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am a programmer in Scala Spark, but I need to do something in Python with PySpark in a project. 
I want to know how to use a customized row => row map transformation in PySpark.

For example: I have a dataframe mydf:

```
id  x1,  x2
1    5    3
2    4    6
3    9    10
```

I want to transform this dataframe into another dataframe, with the map operation on each row.

So I designed a the map function, which take a row as input, and generate a new row as output. So it is a Row => Row map:

```
def mySum (row):

   id = row.id
   result = row.x1 + row.x2

   return Row(id, result)
```

Then I want to use someway in python, which is similar I do in Scala

```
mynewdf = mydf.map( x=> mySum(x))
```

So the expected result looks like:

```
id  result
1    8
2    10
3    19
```

In reality, the custom function is very complicated, so I need a separated function to describe it.

How can I do this in Python with PySpark. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is a `lambda` function:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: mySum(x))
```

But if the function only takes the row as parameter, you can directly pass the function to `map`:

```
df.rdd.map(mySum)
```

---

```
def mySum (row):
    id = row.id
    result = row.x1 + row.x2
    return Row(id=id, result=result)

df.rdd.map(mySum).toDF().show()
+---+------+
| id|result|
+---+------+
|  1|     8|
|  2|    10|
|  3|    19|
+---+------+
```